# How to find the complement of the following graphs?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

[image]

So G is a simple graph, the complement of G, denoted G' is obtained as follows:
The vertex set of G' is identical to the vertex set of G. However 2 distinct vetices v and w of G' are connected by an edge if and only if, v and w are not connected by an edge in G. How can we find the compliment of the above graphs?

for a) am I suppose to draw a graph with 4 edges that doesn't overlap with that original graph?

Same goes for b), so v1 - v4 and v2- v3 ?

Answer (score 1):

This is just a direct application of the definition of compliment.

For the first graph, G' has edges v1-v3 and v4-v3

and the second graph, G' has edges v1-v4, v1-v3, v2-v4, and v2-v3